# How to handle memory between an activity in android

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, memory

I'm new in  android May i know,What are the difference between these and How it use in android code.
OnTrimmemory(),System.gc()Finalize().

Answer (score 2):

**onTrimMemory** with TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN level is actually called before onStop. When onStop is called, it means the activity is really stopping, and the Android OS might kill it right away if it needs to, so you should not expect any more calls to that activity's callbacks aftet that, except for onRestart and sometimes onDestroy.

The  **System.gc()** reason everyone always says to avoid System.gc() is that it is a pretty good indicator of fundamentally broken code. Any code that depends on it for correctness is certainly broken; any that rely on it for performance are most likely broken.

The java.lang.Object.**finalize()** is called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object. A subclass overrides the finalize method to dispose of system resources or to perform other cleanup

Comment: Hi sir,Thank you sir,You said use OnTrimMemory() before onStop(),Can i use this in onPause() state?

Comment: One more doubt sir,Where use System.gc(),Is it use before call Intent or anything else there

Comment: where ever you use null there you call the system.gc() like bitmap or in case here you get out of memory error ya you can pass before passing the intents

Comment: Oh Thank you so much sir! ):